# How to detect mouse left button is being held down in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create code that gets the mouse pointers position when the mouse is left clicked. But when using i use the code below, it only returns the mouse pointer position ONCE when the mouse is left clicked and for it to get the mouse position again the button has to be released and clicked again. How could I modify this code so that if the mouse is left clicked, coordinates of the mouse pointer are returned every 0.1 seconds. Thus the code will be detecting if the left mouse button is being held

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
function getCursorPosition(canvas, event) {
        const rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect()
        const x = event.clientX - rect.left
        const y = event.clientY - rect.top
        console.log("x: " + x + " y: " + y)
    }
canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
        getCursorPosition(canvas, e)
    })
```

Comment: use a timer....

Comment: Can you please be more specific, i am new to JS and do not know how to implement a timer to work in this situation

Comment: Dont’t use mouseclick-event. Instead: After receiving a mousedown-event the mouse is clicked/down until you receive the mouseup-event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use "setInterval" and can specify your own wait time between every console in milliseconds

```
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');

    function getCursorPosition(canvas, event) {
      const rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect()
      const x = event.clientX - rect.left
      const y = event.clientY - rect.top
      console.log("x: " + x + " y: " + y)
    }
    var mousePosition, holding;

    function myInterval() {
      var setIntervalId = setInterval(function() {
        if (!holding) clearInterval(setIntervalId);
        getCursorPosition(canvas, mousePosition);
      }, 100); //set your wait time between consoles in milliseconds here
    }
    canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function() {
      holding = true;
      myInterval();
    })
    canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
      holding = false;
      myInterval();
    })
    canvas.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
      holding = false;
      myInterval();
    })
    canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
      mousePosition = e;
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

you should probably use mousemove event here:

```
 var  holding = false;
 var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
 function getCursorPosition(canvas, event) {
     const rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect()
     const x = event.clientX - rect.left
     const y = event.clientY - rect.top
     console.log("x: " + x + " y: " + y)
 }
 canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
     holding = true;

 })
 canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', function(e) {
     holding = false;

 })
   canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
   if(holding == true){
     getCursorPosition(canvas, e)
   }
 })
```

EDIT: You also need to set holding to false when you leave the button

```
canvas.addEventListener('mouseleave', function(e) {
     holding = false;

 })
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```html
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var mouseIsDown = false;
var mouseInterval = null;
var mouseEvent = null;

function getCursorPosition(canvas, event) {
    const rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect()
    const x = event.clientX - rect.left
    const y = event.clientY - rect.top
    console.log("x: " + x + " y: " + y)
}

canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function (e) {
    mouseEvent = e;
    mouseIsDown = !mouseIsDown;
    getCursorPosition(canvas, e)
    mouseInterval = setInterval(() => {
        getCursorPosition(canvas, mouseEvent)
    }, 100);
})
canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function (e) {
    mouseEvent = e;
})
canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', function (e) {
    mouseIsDown = !mouseIsDown;
    clearInterval(mouseInterval);
})
```

Edit: Depending on what you're trying to accomplish you might want to put the mouseup listener on the window object. Just a thought.